# ¿Se le puede dar formato a un EditText mientras el usuario escribe? Android

Tags: android, android-studio, edittext

Quiero que cuando el usuario introduzca un número (dinero), dicho monto vaya tomando forma según la posición, es decir si el usuario introduce un 1, que en el EditText se vea ***0.01***. Si luego introduce un 5, se vea ***0.15***. Y así sucesivamente.

He visto que lo tienen por lo menos las apps de bancos, así que debe existir alguna manera de hacerlo.

Yo uso TextInputLayout y su respectivo TextInputEditText, no sé si eso afecte.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score -1):

Si se puede! Para lograr esto tienes que sobreescribir el método `TextWatcher` de tu `TextInputEditText`. Este método se llama cada vez que modificar el texto de tu `TextInputEditText`. Entonces quedaría así.

Creamos el método que hace el formato al String que devolerá el TextWatcher.

```
void showFormated(String str){
    int floatPointPosition = 2;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++){
        if(floatPointPosition == str.length() - i){
            result.append(".");
        }
        result.append(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
    }
    textInputEditText.setText(result.toString());
}
```

Luego desde el TextWatcher llamar al método creado anteriormente.

```
textInputEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            showFormated(s.toString());
        }
    });
```

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Bueno, nunca había usado 'StringBuilder' ni su método 'append'. Me faltó agregar que como estamos hablando de dinero, me gustaría agregar las comas también (las de miles y millones). Gracias por contestar, voy a probar tu código. :)

Comment: Ya lo probé, entra en un loop. Me arroja varias veces esto hasta que lo detengo: V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ab49190 nm : ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@89c0a89
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus